# Changing elements in a filtered 2d array without list comprehension while keeping reference to original

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pass-by-reference

I'm not sure how to phrase the question but here's what I'm trying to do.

```
arr_first = np.array([[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,0],[1,1,1,0],[1,1,1,0],[1,1,2,0],[1,1,2,0],[2,2,2,0]])
arr_second = np.array([[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[2,2,2]])
```

I am trying to filter `arr_first` by the first three elements of `arr_second`, resulting in...

```
[array([0, 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, 0])]
[array([1, 1, 1, 0]), array([1, 1, 1, 0]), array([1, 1, 1, 0])]
[array([1, 1, 2, 0]), array([1, 1, 2, 0])]
[array([2, 2, 2, 0])]
```

and then, with the filtered 2d arrays, add 32 to the fourth element of one of the arrays in each 2d array, like this:

```
[[ 0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0 32]
 [ 1  1  1  0]
 [ 1  1  1  0]
 [ 1  1  1 32]
 [ 1  1  2  0]
 [ 1  1  2 32]
 [ 2  2  2 32]]
```

and save that data to the original `arr_first`.

The method I am currently using to do that is with python list comprehension syntax:

```
for i in range(len(arr_second)):
    filtered = [row for row in arr_first if
                        arr_second[i][0] == row[0] and arr_second[i][1] == row[1] and arr_second[i][2] == row[2]]
    choosen_block = random.choice(filtered)
    choosen_block[3] += 32
print(arr_first)
```

This works, but it can be very slow in large data sets. Therefore, I tried filtering by using numpy's in1d:

```
for i in range(len(arr_second)):
    filtered = arr_first[np.in1d(arr_first[:, 0], arr_second[i][0]) &
    np.in1d(arr_first[:, 1], arr_second[i][1]) &
    np.in1d(arr_first[:, 2], arr_second[i][2])]

    choosen_block = random.choice(filtered)
    choosen_block[3] += 32
```

But the problem with this method is that the changes are no longer saved in `arr_first`, unlike the list comprehension method as `arr_first` is no longer in a pass by reference to `filtered`.

I was wondering if someone could give me some guidance on how to fix this by making the changes in `filtered` occur also in `arr_first` instead of having to make another list and with a loop appending `filtered` to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Pandas to `groupby`, `sample`, and update `arr_first`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(arr_first)
inner_len = len(arr_first[0,:])
update_amt = 32
update_ix = 3

df.iloc[(df.groupby(list(range(inner_len)))
           .apply(lambda x: x.sample().index.values[0]).values), 
        update_ix] += update_amt

arr_first
[[ 0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0 32]
 [ 1  1  1  0]
 [ 1  1  1 32]
 [ 1  1  1  0]
 [ 1  1  2 32]
 [ 1  1  2  0]
 [ 2  2  2 32]]
```

**Explanation**

- Pandas lets us group `arr_first` by the unique sets of row values, e.g. `[1,1,1,0]`.  I abbreviated the `groupby` procedure with `range()`, but the command really just says: "Group by column 0, then column 1, then column 2, then column 3".  That effectively groups by the full set of values for each row in `arr_first`.  This seems to effectively mimic your approach of matching `arr_first` rows by the values in `arr_second`.
- Once we've got the rows in groups, we can `sample` one of the rows in each group, and grab its index.
- Then, use the selected indices for the addition update step.
- Even though we're updating `df`, `arr_first` is also updated, as it is (sort of) passed by reference in the creation of `df`.

I tend to think in Pandas, but there may be a Numpy equivalent to these steps.

Comment: Thank you, this method works. However, I was wondering though, later on, would i also be able to group by elements in the array instead of unique row values? such as grouping by when arr_first[0][0] and arr_first[0][1] ignoring arr_first[0][2] by changing the `inner_len` so that it is more like: [[ 0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0 32]
 [ 1  1  1  0]
 [ 1  1  1 32]
 [ 1  1  1  0]
 [ 1  1  2  0]
 [ 1  1  2  0]
 [ 2  2  2 32]]

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Yes, you can group by any column(s) in `df`, which correspond to the individual values in `arr_first` rows (e.g. `[1 1 1 32]`).  As for how you choose to make the groupings, you have a lot of flexibility with Pandas - you can create a function to group any way you want.  See [`groupby docs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).  If you encounter difficulty, open a new question about it or search for [existing SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615760/groupby-with-user-defined-functions-pandas) on the topic.

Comment: If this answer resolved your question, please mark it accepted by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to make your approach work.

First, why does the list comp work in-place, whereas the in1d doesn't? The list comp operates on individual rows of arr_first, each such row is a "view", i.e. a reference into arr_first. By contrast, the in1d soln creates a mask which is then applied to the array. Using masks is one form of "fancy" or "advanced" indexing. Since the subset of the orig array fancy indexing refers to will typically not be representable by offsets and strides this forces a copy and whatever you do afterwards will not affect the orig array.

One easy fix is to not apply the mask. Instead convert it to a vector of row indices and use random.choice directly on this vector:

```
import numpy as np
import random

arr_first = np.array([[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,0],[1,1,1,0],[1,1,1,0],[1,1,2,0],[1,1,2,0],[2,2,2,0]])
arr_second = np.array([[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[2,2,2]])

for i in range(len(arr_second)):
    filtered_idx = np.where(np.in1d(arr_first[:, 0], arr_second[i][0]) &
                            np.in1d(arr_first[:, 1], arr_second[i][1]) &
                            np.in1d(arr_first[:, 2], arr_second[i][2]))[0]

    choosen_block = random.choice(filtered_idx)
    arr_first[choosen_block, 3] += 32

print(arr_first)
```

Sample output:

```
[[ 0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0 32]
 [ 1  1  1 32]
 [ 1  1  1  0]
 [ 1  1  1  0]
 [ 1  1  2  0]
 [ 1  1  2 32]
 [ 2  2  2 32]]
```